# Allowing commas to follow through when converting array to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have an array of character with commas separating them. I need to split an array but retain my comma inbetween each character.

See below for an example array:

```
var myArray = [a,,,b,c,d,,,]
```

There's a comma in there between the characters "a" and "b". I need to retain the comma when converting the array to a string.

The output string needs to resemble this:

`a,bcd,`

This is what i'm currently doing to retain the commas:

```
myArray.toString().replace(/,/g, "");
```

Comment: `var myArray = [a,,,b,c,d,,,]` is not a valid array. How are you declaring it? Did it give you an error

Comment: @ozil I meant ["a",",","b","c","d",","]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you use :

```
var myArray = [a,,,b,c,d,,,];
var str = myArray.join();
```

This will give a string of array elements, preserving the commas.

Comment: No it wont unless array is like this ['a',',',',','b','c','d',',',','];

Comment: I guess, given the array is [a,',',b,c,d,',',] where a,b,c and d are defined variables then `str = myArray.join('');` is needed since if an empty string argument is omitted `Array.prototype.join()` by default joins the elements with a comma among them.

Answer (score 3):

The Array's `toString()` method basically does a `join(",")` which is why you are getting the extra commas in your string.

Instead use `join("")` if you want to join the elements without the delimiter being added as part of the string

```js
var myArray = ["a",",","b","c","d",",",]
document.body.innerText = myArray.join("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have a sparse array and want to extract only filled values and convert it to string ? Here is one, probably not the best, solution :

```
    var myArray = ['a',',',',','b',',','c']
var resultArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    if(myArray[i] !== ','){// allow 0, false, null values, but not undefined
       resultArray.push(myArray[i]);
    }
}

console.log(resultArray);
```

Working plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/55T6PGI9DuTlvy6k88hr?p=preview, check the console of your broswer.

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle ? I think the array will be like this ['a',',',',','b'...] and there is the problem

Comment: i created a plnkr, see my edited answer. You can check the result by opening your debogguer console in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an actual array of strings and you wanted only those with actual values, you could use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter out any non-undefined ones :

```
// Your example array
var input = ['a',,,'b','c','d',,,];
// Remove any undefined elements
var output = input.filter(function(e){ return e; }); // yields ['a','b','c','d']
```

You could then use the [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function to create a string with your elements :

```
var result = output.join(); // yields "a,b,c,d"
```

**Example Snippet**

```js
var input = ['a',,,'b','c','d',,,];
document.write('INPUT: ' + input + '<br />');
var output = input.filter(function(e){ return e; });
document.write('OUTPUT: ' + output);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to maintain the centre comma you should create your array as

```
var myArray = [a,",",b,c,d,",",];
```

this will then treat the middle comma in the set of 3 as a string containing that character rather than the array seperator

Answer (score 1):

You could change your regex, to replace `item,item` for `item item`.

```
 myArray.toString().replace(/([a-z,]),([a-z,])/g, "$1$2")
```